# How can I get object with query builder in laravel

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm new to laravel.

In RouteServiceProvider when I'm fetching the article using following code

```
$router->bind('articles',function($id) {
    return \App\Article::active()->findOrFail($id);
});
```

I get an object:

```
Article {#323 ▼
 #fillable: array:18 [▶]
 #dates: array:1 [▶]
 ...
}
```

But when I build a custom query using QueryBuilder

```
public static function getArticleById($id) {
    return DB::table('articles')
            ->leftJoin('news','articles.news_id','=','news.id')
            ->select('articles.*','reports.name as selected_report_id')
            ->where('articles.id',$id)
            ->get();
}
```

I get array:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#342 ▼
    +"id": 40
    ...
  }
]
```

Comment: Use `Eloquent` instead of query builder or use model [`hydrate`](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_hydrate) method.

Comment: In your RouteServiceProvider you are using Eloquent and in your custom query you are using DB class, Eloquent always return object